# Prove that this graph is k-connected

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and minimum degree $\delta \ge (n+k-2)/2$, with $k\ge 2$. Prove that $G$ is $k$-connected.

Comment: Suppose the graph were not connected.  What can you say about the sizes of the components?

Comment: Well, if we assume there are $m$ components $Q_1,...,Q_m$ then each must have at least $(n+k)/2$ vertices. So $|V(G)| \ge m(n+k)/2$ which for $m \ge 2$ gives $k\le 0$. So $m=1$ therefore G is connected, and also $n\ge k\ge 2$.

Comment: Yes, you can also reason in a dual manner and claim that at least one component has at most $n/2$ vertices, which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: But do you know how we would go about proving that it is k-connected?

Comment: Suppose there are $k - 1$ vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{k - 1}$ such that after deleting these vertices we get graph $H$ with $m \ge 2$ components. What can you say about minimum vertex degree in $H$? What can you say about the number of components in $H$?

Answer (score 1):

First remove any $k-1$ nodes. We get a new graph $G'$ with  $|V(G')|=n-k+1$ and a minimum of $\delta(G') = (n-k)/2$. Assume that $G'$ is not connected, then
there exist two distinct nodes with distinct neighbors. The neighbors are at
least $\delta(G')*2 \ge n -k$. Add the aforementioned nodes and we have a minimum
number of $n-k+2 > |V(G')|$ nodes. Therefore $G'$ is connected and thus $G$ is $k$-connected.